# R - ReporteRs Package. Is it possible to apply conditional formatting to text?

Tags: r, formatting, powerpoint, flextable, reporters

I have following `dataframe`:

```
> View(AuthorsMM)

    Autor    #  Sentiment
1   Autor 1  33 J
2   Autor 2  33 J
3   Autor 3  22 K
4   Autor 4  18 L
5   Autor 5  16 L
6   Autor 6  15 K
7   Autor 7  15 L
8   Autor 8  15 K
9   Autor 9  15 K
10  Autor 10 14 K
```

I am using the package `ReporteRs` to send this data.frame as `flextable` to Powerpoint:

```
AuthorsMM_ft <- FlexTable( data = head(AuthorsMM,10), header.columns = TRUE )
```

I define the sentiment column with the followig text properties:

```
AuthorsMM_ft[, 3] = textProperties( color = 'white', font.weight = 'bold', font.family = 'Wingdings', font.size = 12 )
```

which makes Powerpoint display different emoticons (because of the Wingdings trueType) according to the content of the column.

However, I would like to aditionally apply different colors (green, yellow, red) to the text depending of the content. Therefore:

- if (Sentiment == "J") then  textProperties( **color = 'green'**,
  font.weight = 'bold', font.family = 'Wingdings', font.size = 12 )
- if (Sentiment == "K") then  textProperties( **color = 'yellow'**,
  font.weight = 'bold', font.family = 'Wingdings', font.size = 12 )
- if (Sentiment == "L") then  textProperties( **color = 'red'**,
  font.weight = 'bold', font.family = 'Wingdings', font.size = 12 )

It's that possible using this package?

Comment: you could use `dput(AuthorsMM)` to make the example easier to reproduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

This code shows how to do it:

```
library(ReporteRs)

# define the data frame - extracted with dput()
AuthorsMM <- structure(list(Autor = c("Autor 1", "Autor 2", "Autor 3", "Autor 4", 
                                      "Autor 5", "Autor 6", "Autor 7", "Autor 8", "Autor 9", "Autor 10"
), `#` = c(33L, 33L, 22L, 18L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L), 
Sentiment = c("J", "J", "K", "L", "L", "K", "L", "K", "K", 
              "K")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                             -10L), .Names = c("Autor", "#", "Sentiment"), spec = structure(list(
                                                                               cols = structure(list(Autor = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                         "collector")), `#` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                          "collector")), Sentiment = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "collector"))), .Names = c("Autor", "#", "Sentiment")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))

# conditional formatting:
base_text_prop = textProperties(font.size = 12, 
                            color = "black",
                            font.weight = 'bold',
                            font.family = 'Wingdings')

myCellProps = cellProperties(padding = 5)

AuthorsMM_ft <- FlexTable(data = head(AuthorsMM,10), 
                      header.columns = TRUE,
                      body.text.props = base_text_prop)

AuthorsMM_ft[AuthorsMM$Sentiment == 'J',3] = chprop(base_text_prop, color = 'green')
AuthorsMM_ft[AuthorsMM$Sentiment == 'K',3] = chprop(base_text_prop, color = 'yellow')
AuthorsMM_ft[AuthorsMM$Sentiment == 'L',3] = chprop(base_text_prop, color = 'red')
AuthorsMM_ft
```

[image]

For some reason defining `textProperties` within `FlexTable` didn't work. When I used `background.color` it seemed to change the format.

More examples of [changing properties](https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/formatting_properties.html#change_properties) and [conditional formatting](https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/FlexTable.html#conditional_formatting_example) in FlexTables.